# Integration services : Implement onSuccess event in ssis. How to ?

Tags: ssis, event-handling, ssis-2008

I have a sequence container with multiple Execute package tasks in it. For each task what I want is to update a record in SQL table if the package executes successfully.

I looked into event handling but there is no OnSuccess event in SSIS. I have used OnError event handling for it and that seems to be working fine.

Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the update in an execute package task right after the execute package task.  If there is a failure the update will not happen.

Comment: You mean adding a Execute SQL task after Execute package task? Wouldn't that fail the entire sequence container? I am not sure what is the sequence. I have OnError event on the execute package task.

Comment: You mean adding a Execute SQL task after Execute package task? -
 Yes
Wouldn't that fail the entire sequence container? - Sequence container, all tasks will run but if one fails the container will fail and go through the fail branch of the control flow. If you want it to only continue processing on success consider changing your Sequence container logic or not using it at all

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to adding a component ***after*** your SQL query? This is using all scripts but the same principle can be applied if you wanted to use a Execute SQL Task or any other type of component. That way you can still run parallel, your table would be updated with ONLY the tasks that completed and your next item(s) in your control flow would still be valid

[image: Parallel update on success SSIS]

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible ways of doing this

> 1: You can wrap each Execute package tasks inside its own container
>   and then 
>          use precedence constraints with success and failure
>
> 2 You can inside each package handle your flow with update statements when it succeeds with constraints also.

But when your package task 1 fails, the main container will also fail and then your package will also fail, so consider setting maxmiumerrorcount to -1 or 999. 
Then your MasterPackage will not fail, and your log will control for you which packages has failed.

[image]